# UIView change background color to image

Tags: iphone, uiview

I managed to successfully change some of my UIView background to a custom image using
`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myCustomBackground.jpg"]];`

But it does not work on a particular view in a controller that is presented modally as such,

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];    
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
[loginViewController release];
[navController release];
```

It seems like `self.view` inside this controller is behind the view it was showing.

**EDIT**

LoginViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myCustomBackground.jpg"]];
}
```

self.view in this case seems to be hidden behind the current view that it's displaying. I did not add any subView beforehand.

Comment: Can we see the code that set the background in LoginViewController and what method it's in?

Comment: @picciano Please see edited answer. It's added in but somehow self.view is behind the current view it's showing.

Comment: What LoginView contains? Labels? Table? Scroll?

Comment: @Nekto It has a UIView. Within the UIView, includes UIScrollView, UILabels and UIButtons all created on IB. The view that worked had similar items inside too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments, your view contains `UIScrollView`, `UILabel` and `UIButton`.

You should set to all this subviews property `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`. Hopefully that would help.

If you are editing subview in IB then you should find property `Background` in Attributes Inspector and select `Clear Color` (for all subviews).